# Can i remove an item from localStorage for every user?

Tags: angular, caching

When i do a GET-request to get a logo, im saving the logo as JSON in LocalStorage so i can just get it from there next time without having to do another http-request:

```
  getLogo(): Observable<Picture> {
    const cachedLogoString: string = localStorage.getItem('logo');
    if (cachedLogoString) { // if cached, return the cached logo
      const cachedLogo: Picture = JSON.parse(cachedLogoString);
      return Observable.of(cachedLogo);
    }

    // if not cached, do the request and cache it
    const logoObservable: Observable<Picture> = this.http.get<Picture>(BASE_URL + 'logo', this.authService.setHeaders('application/json'))
      .pipe(
        share(),
        catchError(this.handleService.error.bind(this))
      );
    this.cacheLogo(logoObservable);
    return logoObservable;
  }

  private cacheLogo(logoObservable: Observable<Picture>): void {
    logoObservable.subscribe(logoToBeCached => {
      localStorage.setItem('logo', JSON.stringify(logoToBeCached));
    });
  }
```

This works fine, the problem i have is that im not sure what im supposed to do when i update the logo:

```
  updatePicture(picture: Picture): Observable<Picture> {
    return this.http.put<Picture>(BASE_URL + picture.id, picture, this.authService.setHeaders('application/json'))
      .pipe(
        tap(() => this.handleService.success('Bild bearbeitet')),
        catchError(this.handleService.error.bind(this))
      );
  }
```

I would have to remove the logo from the localStorage after it was updated to get the new logo during the next GET request instead of getting the old one from localStorage. I could do that with `localStorage.remove('logo')`. But the problem is that that would only remove the logo from the localStorage of that person doing that update. Every other person would still have the old logo in localStorage and doesnt know that it was updated.

Is there anything i can do here? I cant think of any way to globally remove the logo from everyones localStorage.

Comment: every user needs to fetch the latest value to get reflected globally. you can not make changes on your local and have them reflected globally.

Comment: you could keep a logo expiry say a day or few hours and instead of using from local storage if expiry is over you can again use http get to receive the new logo. Its like periodically checking if the logo is changed

Comment: @biff should i give logo a new property `expiryDate` ? So when i get it from `localStorage` i check whether the logo expired and do a http request if it did. But of which type would that `expiryDate` be? Never did something in this direction. Would `expiryDate` just be a normal `date` and i guess i could just compare it to the `currentDate()` and if `currentDate()` is greater than `expiryDate()` it means that the logo expired. Is that the usual way to do this?

Comment: ya you can use the above logic. I think this is the way to do it, I'm using this logic in my local storage.